# Why is self-organization related to scale invariance?

Tags: non-linear-systems, complex-systems, scale-invariance

A lot of books mention that Scale Invariance is a property of Self-Organized critical processes, but fail to mention why.

Why is Scale Invariance a property of Self-Organized processes?

Comment: perhaps a duplicate http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/24835/scale-invariance-and-self-organized-criticality

Answer (score 1):

You got the wrong keyword: it's **critical** systems that are scale invariant, while the *self organized* part means their own dynamics can take them to a critical state.

As Wolphram pointed out, you can find more details in the answer to the question [Scale invariance and self organized criticality](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/24835/75633).